# Generic exception when trying to save uploaded image file

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, c#-4.0

When trying to save an uploaded file, I get this error and are having some difficulties solving it:

ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

It's a very specific exception message!

This is my code.

```
// Gets the original image.
byte[] original = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
file.InputStream.Read(original, 0, (int)file.InputStream.Length);

// Redimensions the original image and saves it for each of the desired pictures classes.
foreach (ClassDetails c in picturesClasses)
{
    byte[] resized = Images.Resize(original, new Size(c.Width, c.Height), c.ResizeToExactProportions);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(resized);
    Image resizedImage = Image.FromStream(stream);

    uniqueFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".png");

    // The exception happens HERE **************************************************
    resizedImage.Save(Path.Combine(c.Path, uniqueFilename), ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Please, any idea of what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: It happens where I wrote // The exception happens HERE ********** (last line in code). But I already solved the problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... I love it when problems are solved fast!

The path I had was a relative one. I had to use the Server.MapPath method. See below:

```
resizedImage.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(c.Path, uniqueFilename)), ImageFormat.Png);
```